# Create one only foreach loop for all controls in a GroupControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a form that contains a GroupControl in this GroupControl  there are some controls.

I want when I click on a button to change the properties of thos controls to `control.Properties.ReadOnly = false;`

So I created this code :

```
      foreach (TextEdit te in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
      {
           te.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
      }

      foreach (TextEdit te in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
      {
           te.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
      }
      foreach (DateEdit de in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
      {
           de.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
      }
      foreach (ComboBoxEdit cbe in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
      {
           cbe.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
      }
      foreach (MemoEdit me in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
      {
           me.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
      }
      foreach (CheckEdit ce in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
      {
           ce.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
      }
```

That's worked but I have to create a foreach loop for every control.

I also tried this

```
foreach (Control control in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
{
    control.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

But System.Windows.Forms.Control does not contain a definition for 'Properties'

**How can I create one only foreach loop for all controls in a GroupControl?**

Comment: Try using `dynamic`. Lookup MSDN if you do not know what it does. To use it just replace `Control control` with `dynamic control`.

Comment: I can't use the dynamic type it gives me this error :

`The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: `dynamic` was introduced in `C# 4`. What version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you like you are using a group of controls that all derive from the same BaseClass.  Is that BaseClass, BaseEdit?

If so, do this...

```
foreach(object control in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
{
    BaseEdit editableControl = control as BaseEdit;
    if(editableControl != null)
        editableControl.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

I'm making this guess from this link (it has controls like the one's you are using).
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEditMembersTopicAll

Comment: there are other controls in the GroupControl like LabelControl and ButtonControl so that I can't use that code.

I think I have to make an exception for the other controls but I don't know how !

Comment: yes .. I tried this but it gives me this code  
`foreach (BaseEdit be in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
            {
                be.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
            }`
but it gives me this error :

`Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl' to type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit'.`

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Properties' and no extension method 'Properties' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the base class approach. But since you said only a few types need to be 'ReadOnly = false', you can do something like this

```
foreach (Control c in InformationsGroupControl.Controls)
{
   if(c is TextEdit || c is DateEdit || c is ComboBoxEdit || c is MemoEdit || c is CheckEdit)
       (c as BaseEdit).Properties.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

incluide linq.

usse the following code:

```
foreach (var edit in InformationsGroupControl.Controls.OfType<BaseEdit>())
{
    edit.Properties.ReadOnly = false;
}
```